# GET request to remote server using Swagger

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger

I'm trying to use `Swagger` in my **ASP.NET Core project**. I have a `controller` with a method like this

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/MyMethod")]    
public class ApiController : Controller
{
    private HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    /// <summary>
    /// Get api request
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="query"></param>
    [HttpGet]
    public void Get(string query)
    {
        var response = client.GetAsync(query).Result;
    }
}
```

When I start the project, I can run my request, but it always uses 
**localhost** as shown in figure:

[image]

Can someone please explain how can I execute a request not to localhost? For example, like
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=City

Comment: Well, Swagger generates a UI for **your** API, how could it know Google Maps' API endpoints?

Comment: Remember that swagger ui is submitting the request via the browser. You cannot make a browser request to an API that is not CORS enabled (or javascript is being served down by that server that lets you call it) by design. If the API is CORS enabled then you will need to make sure to format your request correctly.